# Browser plug-in to warn user when spending a long time on a site

Tags: productivity

Is there a browser plug-in that will warn the user ever X seconds with a popup and/or audio alarm when they are browsing predefined sites? Example: I go to Facebook and get sucked in and before I realized it 10 minutes has passed. I'd like an alarm to go off every 30 seconds on this site to tell me to get-out-of-there.

Comment: Technical solutions to "people" issues like these are usually toothless. If you spend ten minutes now, even though you "know" you shouldn't, you will spend the same time later, even though a program tells you that you shouldn't. A good solution does not exist on the technical level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Chrome, try the [StayFocusd](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji) extension.

If you're a Firefox user, use the [Leech Block](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/leechblock/) add-on.

I think the plugin for Chrome is a better plugin overall.